# Bruhat decomposition with an example

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I read somewhere that given an invertible matrix, we can decompose it into a product of lower triangular and upper triangular matrices up to a permutation matrix using the
Gauss elimination method.

So we have $GL_n(\mathbb C)=\cup_{w \in S_n}BwB$, where $B$ is the set of all upper triangular matrices.

Could someone please explain with an example (say with a $4 \times 4$ matrix) how the permutation matrix come to the picture (possibly the elementary rwo operations corresponding to the permutation of rows) and how the dimension of $BwB/B$ is $l(w)$, the length of the $w$.

Comment: You've almost answered the question yourself. Perform Gaussian elimination but keep track of your row operations and the matrices that represents them. You should be able to see that up to permutation the product of all those matrices can be written as lower triangular. There are only 3 types of operation so this is not too hard to prove (and a good exercise). This particular case is also called the LUP decomposition so you can find a direct proof under that name